# Contact form not sending email and no notification

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

working on contact form for my website. All tree form fields are validating correctly somehow the email is not send but looks page is loading again. Can anyone check my code and tell me where could be a problem here. Would like temail to be sent and notification to the user shown.

Contact form:

```
<form role="form" id="contactForm">
     <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Wpisz swoje imię, nazwisko" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn-block">Wyślij wiadomość</button>
<div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden">Message Submitted!</div>
     </div>
    </form>
```

Java sripts within same html file as form:

```
   <script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var owl = $("#owl-hero");

    owl.owlCarousel({

        navigation: false, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed: 1,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        singleItem: true,
        transitionStyle: "fade"

    })});


    </script>



    <script>
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});

function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            }
        }
    })};
}
function formSuccess(){
    $( "#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
}


</script>
```

PHP file (process.php) :

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$EmailTo = "roger@gth.com.pl";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $message, $email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
   echo "success";
}else{
    echo "invalid";
}

?>
```

**for further dicussion:**

my top code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="pl">

        <head>

            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

            <title>my site</title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/ico.png">

            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta name="description" content="jakiś wyraz">
            <meta name="keywords" content="">
            <meta name="author" content="strona">

            <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
            <link href="bootstrap-assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <!-- Style -->
            <link href="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="plugins/Lightbox/dist/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="plugins/Icons/et-line-font/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="plugins/animate.css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <!-- Icons Font -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>



     <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var owl = $("#owl-hero");

        owl.owlCarousel({

            navigation: false, // Show next and prev buttons
            slideSpeed: 1,
            paginationSpeed: 400,
            singleItem: true,
            transitionStyle: "fade"

        })});


        </script>



        <script>
    $("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            // handle the invalid form...
        } else {
            // everything looks good!
            event.preventDefault();
            submitForm();
        }
    });

    function submitForm(){
        // Initiate Variables With Form Content
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/form-process.php",
            data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
            success : function(text){
                if (text == "success"){
                    formSuccess();
                }
            }
        });
}
    function formSuccess(){
        $( "#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
    }


    </script>    
        </head>
```

**i notice couple errors in console please help me also to fix it.:**

error type: `SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined`

on this line:

```
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
```

error type: `SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined`
at the end on own.carousel script here:

});

Comment: Maybe email is working fine but not getting ajax response

Comment: Instead of `echo "success";` and `" invalid"` use ...` echo 1;` and `echo 0; `

Comment: In ajax .... if (text == 1){ // success }

Comment: Different file names for your php script?

Comment: Are you sure the mail() function is not disabled on your server? Try using SMTP instead.

Comment: no because 'my very old' contact form is sending email.

Comment: tried also with echo 0 and echo 1 - same...

Comment: as process.php lies besides index.html i changed also this line (still same problem ..) : url: "php/form-process.php",   to this line: url: "process.php",

Comment: Have you done `console.log(text)` in your success function? What does the response look like?

Comment: have some problem on the line: $("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {    this error:  SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined

Comment: Did you load jQuery with a `<script src>` tag? That needs to go before the validator function.

Comment: i am not sure if i got it at all - i will paste what i have at the top of my code - please check if you can...

Comment: i think main issue could be related to just added problems on my site, can anyone give a solution as an answer?

Comment: $ undefined means ... Make sure jquery included properly

Comment: i just added to my head is it enough? : <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: anyway still same problems..

Comment: OK instead of $ sign.   Use `jQuery`

Comment: could you please make an answer?

Comment: Where u r using `$` in jquery.... Just replace with `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't loaded the jQuery library (or at least prior to attempting to use it based on your `<head>` tag from above), add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

before useing the `$` function.

After jQuery has resolved, remove the syntax error cased by the extra `}` in your `submitForm` function -right in between the `)` and the `;`.

Comment: its there look at head again...

Comment: and '$' is still undefined?

Comment: now i have for this line: $("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {        SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'validator'

Comment: i removed additional } - see my updated code in main topic but still has the error message as above

Comment: `validator` is not a built in library, you will need to include this script as well.

Comment: could you be so kind and help me how to attach this 'validator'?

Comment: <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js></script>

Comment: ok no message about validator... but still the same no mail after send and page is like you would refresh after submit